# How to have an object autowired and injected just once in a JUnit+Spring Test?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I have a test case where I have an `@Autowired Foo foo` which I need to have injected just once, so all the test methods could re-use the same data `foo` has. What is currently happening is that upon every `@Test` method's invocation, the `foo` bean is cleanly re-loaded by Spring.

Is is possible to load this bean just once for the whole test class and how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is probably environment specific since they differ in the loading of the Spring context. For example, Eclipse does not automatically reload the context between tests but Maven does.

I would suggest that you write a `@Before` method that copies the `@Autowired` reference into another field and have your tests use that field.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but how about beans that are injected transitively in dependent beans, which are not directly defined in the test?

Comment: that might be an issue, and actually my solution may be a bad idea as well as the Context might be closed and the beans no longer valid. Seems kludgy to use a bean from a context that has gone out of scope.

Comment: Not really the kind of answer I was looking for, but this is a solution... Thanks again!